# stock chart volume by price

Tags: php, charts

I am currently using php, mysql, amcharts. I have tried to find different charts but cannot find one supporting "Volume by Price" chart, i.e. with normal price candlestick chart, on the same graph(overlay), add the horizontal bar chart for the price on the y-axis that indicate the volume transacted at that price level. Please advise how can I do so . Thanks a lot.

The desired output is per attached below got from internet.

sample graph:
http://www.financialsense.com/sites/default/files/users/u26/images/2010/0809-spy.jpg

http://www.sierrachart.com/images/doc_VolumeByPrice_img2.png

Answer (score 0):

Interesting graph. I suspect most out of the box charting applications don't support this type of chart as it requires access to order book data. What I would suggest doing is:

1. Creating the candlestick chart
2. Create the bar chart, specifying exactly the dimensions of the candle chart.
3. Overlay them using a graphics program or something.